# xinit: No such file or directory no server "X" in PATH

Tags: linux, kde

installed kde using the cmd:

```
yum install @kde
```

now I want to switch to kde . I tried :

```
$xinit .xinitrc.kde -- :1
```

I got :

```
    xinit:  No such file or directory (errno 2):  no server "X" in PATH

Use the -- option, or make sure that /usr/bin is in your path and
that "X" is a program or a link to the right type of server
for your display.  Possible server names include:

    Xorg        Common X server for most displays
    Xvfb        Virtual frame buffer
    Xfake       kdrive-based virtual frame buffer
    Xnest       X server nested in a window on another X server
    Xephyr      kdrive-based nested X server
```

Any help?

Comment: Have you tried **yum install @xorg** ? Not that I know which distro you're using, or what their package group names might be, or why kde doesn't depend on X it in their case ...

Comment: that's the right answer. It worked . pls post this as an answer .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried **yum install @xorg** ?